# Script not executing on page load

Tags: jquery, html, css

Displaying a message after a page has been refreshed can be accomplished with the following:

HTML (insert anywhere in the BODY tag):

```
<div id="dvLoading"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#dvLoading {
    background:url(../theImages/loader.gif) no-repeat center center;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
    z-index: 9999999999999999;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
    $('#dvLoading').fadeOut(2000);
});
```

Only issue is, it's working in IE but not in FF or Chrome. The loader image fades away after a few seconds but in FF and Chrome the image just stays in it's place and doesn't fade away.

Comment: $(window).bind("load", function() {  --> $(window).load(function() {

Comment: How about pressing "ALT + F4"?

Comment: @PlantTheIdea correct short number is `404`

Comment: Seems to work fine in Chrome, at least with a Google Doodle: http://jsfiddle.net/cvWB6/

Comment: The idea of "CSS/HTML/JavaScript/jQuery/etc not working" is just absurd. It's like saying "Oh God, English no longer functions correctly!!" No sir/mam, you're just doing it wrong. Certainly there are bugs and issues in the code (it'll always be a work in progress - [just like English](http://public.oed.com/the-oed-today/recent-updates-to-the-oed/march-2013-update/new-words-list-march-2013/)), but it works exactly as it's presently designed to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wiring it up the standard jQuery way ought to work across all browsers:

```
$(function () {
    $('#dvLoading').fadeOut(2000);
});
```

or, if you're not using jQuery in No Conflict mode,

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('#dvLoading').fadeOut(2000);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the proper answer!

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(document).ready`

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#dvLoading').fadeOut(2000);
});
```

Example Here:
http://jsfiddle.net/apR7C/